# AngularJS Error Controller with this name is not registered

Tags: python, angularjs, django

im having a headache with this one, im not very skilled in Angular but was the only way to check 'today dolar value'.

This is my dolar.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("DolarCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.dailyIndicators = '';
    $http.get('https://mindicador.cl/api/dolar').then(function(res) {  //.success was changed for .then // 
        $scope.dailyIndicators = res.data.serie[0].valor;
    })
});
```

base.html

```
    <body ng-app>
    <p ng-controller="DolarCtrl"> Dolar acutal: $ {{DolarCtrl.dailyIndicators}}</p>
</body>
```

but at soon as i refresh the page, i got this error:

```
 error: [$controller:ctrlreg]

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=DolarCtrl
       at angular.js:99
       at angular.js:11646
       at ga (angular.js:10677)
       at q (angular.js:10462)
       at g (angular.js:9801)
       at g (angular.js:9804)
       at angular.js:9666
       at angular.js:1947
       at m.$eval (angular.js:19356)
       at m.$apply (angular.js:19455)
```

any ideas? i dont know if you guys needs more info.

thanks!

Comment: please only use {{dailyIndicators}} instread of {{DolarCtrl.dailyIndicators}} in the base.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code.

1. `ng-app` needs a name of the module that you're creating as your root module.
   So `ng-app="app"` must be there.
2. Also, since you're assigning everything to `$scope`, you don't need to do `DolarCrtl.` in your `p` tag.

Here, give this a try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <p ng-controller="DolarCtrl"> Dolar acutal: $ {{dailyIndicators}}</p>
</body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module("app", []);

  app.controller("DolarCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.dailyIndicators = '';
    $http.get('https://mindicador.cl/api/dolar').then(function(res) { //.success was changed for .then // 
      $scope.dailyIndicators = res.data.serie[0].valor;
    })
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: yeeeh, now the errors are gone but nothing show up, maybe the link (API( is bad.   Thanks for your early answer, im gonna keep searching.

Comment: @Nembone, nope. The API is not bad. Just click on the Run code snippet and you should see the value you are expecting. Maybe you have not specified the path to your controller correctly in your HTML.

Comment: you are right, but sadly at django doesnt show the value... ill keep looking, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Html should look like this:

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <body ng-app>
    <p ng-controller="DolarCtrl"> Dolar acutal: $ {{dailyIndicators}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript should look like this:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("DolarCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.dailyIndicators = '';
    $http.get('https://mindicador.cl/api/dolar').then(function(res) {  //.success was changed for .then // 
        $scope.dailyIndicators = res.data.serie[0].valor;
    })
});
```